# Displaying markers within viewport for different country in google map?

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, geolocation

I have multiple location. One is from Netherlands and one from India. How to display both country marker in google map view port?

Currently only Netherlands markers are displayed. So I have to drag map for watch Indian location marker. How can I get both in same view port without dragging?

```
var properties = {
    "locations": [
        {
            "property_title": "Properties 1",
            "property_avg_review": "4.75",
            "property_price": "$4",
            "property_latitude": "21.232689",
            "property_longitude": "72.865141"
        },
        {
            "property_title": "Chalet Type B (vb. Westerbergen)",
            "property_avg_review": 0,
            "property_price": "$400.25",
            "property_latitude": "52.7121",
            "property_longitude": "6.39892"
        }
    ]
};

function initialize(response) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    locations = properties.locations;

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        var title = locations[i]['property_title'];
        var avg_review = locations[i]['property_avg_review']
        var address = locations[i]['property_address'];
        var price = locations[i]['property_price'];
        var latitude = locations[i]['property_latitude'];
        var longitude = locations[i]['property_longitude'];
        var data_index = i;



        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
            map: map,
            icon: normalIcon(),
            label: {
                text: price,
                color: 'black',
                fontSize: '16px',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                marginTop: '7px'
            }
        });

        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())

        markers['hover_' + data_index] = marker;
        markers['hover_' + data_index].setZIndex(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + data_index);

        var rating = parseFloat(avg_review);
        var numStars = 5;
        var fullStar = new Array(Math.floor(rating + 1)).join('<i class="fa fa-star"></i>');
        var halfStar = ((rating % 1) !== 0) ? '<i class="fa fa-star-half-empty"></i>' : '';
        var noStar = new Array(Math.floor(numStars + 1 - rating)).join('<i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>');

        var box_content = '<div class="property_box_map">';
        box_content += '<div class="property_review_price">';
        box_content += '<label><b>From</b></label> ' + price + ' | <span class="stars">' + fullStar + halfStar + noStar + '</span>';
        box_content += '</div>';
        box_content += '</div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, box_content, infowindow) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(box_content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                activeWindow = infowindow;
            }
        })(marker, box_content, infowindow));

        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {

            var iwOuter = jQuery('.gm-style-iw');
            var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();
            // Remove the background shadow DIV
            iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({ 'display': 'none' });
            // Remove the white background DIV
            iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({ 'display': 'none' });

        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
        if (typeof activeWindow != "undefined") {
            activeWindow.close();
        }
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

//get normal icon for map.
function normalIcon() {
    return {
        url: "https://cdn.smokymountains.com/static/maps/pointer-normal.png",
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(80, 40),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(32, 65),
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(40, 17)
    };
}

//get active icon for map whenever hover on property.
function activeIcon() {
    return {
        url: "https://cdn.smokymountains.com/static/maps/pointer-active.png",
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(80, 40),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(32, 65),
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(40, 17)
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add this `--> var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();`

before  this line `--> for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {`

add this `--> bounds.extend(marker.position);`

before this line `--> bounds.extend(marker.position);`

add this `--> map.fitBounds(bounds);`

at end `} of --> function initialize(response) {`

Comment: could you please edit your answer with your suggestions impemented into the code (or improve readability in any other way)?